# How do I rewrite URLs without access to IIS using C# and ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I am looking for a solution to rewrite URLs that have query strings so that the query string creates permanent link. For example: the query string ?u=test would become http://www.website.com/profile/test

I am new to URL rewriting, but am open to any suggestions you may have. I don't have access to IIS as I'm using shared virtual hosting.

Comment: iis version, asp.net version?

Comment: My host runs Windows Server 2008 so I bet IIS is 7.0. ASP .NET is version 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ASP.NET routing engine (introduced in .NET 3.5 SP1), see this article for quick-start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx

BTW, although outdated, you should read Scott Gu's post sighted by Danish for various options.

Comment: I just found that my host installed ASP .NET 4.0 and I upgraded my site to run on ASP .NET 4.0. It has ASP .NET routing built-in. This turned out to be the easiest solution. Thanks for showing me the ASP .NET routing technique.

Answer (score 2):

You cant have extension-less URL without configuring it in the IIS as ISAPI wouldn't know how to handle that request.

Scott Gu has an [excellent post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) with various approaches to URL rewrite.

Comment: IIS7 added native rewriting facilities, which postdate that article by a year.